# How to get multiplpe images from array to xml

Tags: arrays, image

how to get correct xml output and make an $xml_item with all images from array?

Thanks

```
foreach ($item->pictures->picture as $img_url) {
                        $data_test[$processed]['img'][] = (string)$img_url;
                    }
```

```
Outputs:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ordercode] => 0333030
            [number] => AH-63/SW
            [slug] => ah-63-sw
            [url] => https://monacor.sk/product/ah-63-sw
            [name] => Monacor AH-63/SW
            [stock] => 0
            [availableathand] => 0
            [foreignstock] => 12
            [price] => 17,60
            [description] => blabla
            [manufacturer] => MON
            [weight] => 0.24 kg
            [category] => 
            [img] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://monacor.sk/uploads/resizedImages/normal_5a5e480bcfdaa_C333030AI.jpg
                    [1] => https://monacor.sk/uploads/resizedImages/normal_5cda4eabbbe80_C333030Z.jpg
                )

        )
```

With $xml_item->addChild('IMG', (string)$img_url); it posts only first image.